# Loading objects of different entity types at the same time

Tags: hibernate

Is there a way I can get a set of object belonging to different types in a parallel fashion? I  am doing a Read for say a PurchaseOrder object, an Invoice object and the Product object for which I have the Ids. Instead of doing a sequential session.get()s, is there a way to load them together using Hibernate. If each of those get() takes 30ms, I would save 60ms if I could do them parallely instead of sequentially. I am only doing a read and not doing any updates in this transaction. Something like getMulti() would be great!

Comment: What's the relationship between the content of your question and its title?

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, corrected it. Was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, Hibernate must use SQL queries to load the data from the database. And AFAIK, it's not possible to load three rows from unrelated tables at once. So this is not possible either using the Hibernate API.

If the entities are connected through associations, you can load everything at once using a HQL query, though. For example, if a PurchaseOrder has a ManytoOne association with a Product and a ManyToOne with an Invoice, you may load the PurchaseOrder with its invoice and its product using the following HQL query:

```
select o from PurchaseOrder o
left join fetch o.invoice i
left join fetch o.product p
where o.id = :orderId
```